# What is the easiest way to pass multiple variables in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a form that uses a JQuery Json post.  I have 10+ textboxes on the page.  I have variables passed the only way I know... is there another way to pass multiple variables?

```
$('#nameSubmit').click(function() {
    var status = document.getElementById('Select2').value;
    var lob = document.getElementById('LOB').value;
    var lName = document.getElementById('LName').value;
    var fName = document.getElementById('FName').value;
    var city = document.getElementById('City').value;
    var state = document.getElementById('State').value;
    $.post("Home/LoadTable", { Status: status, LOB: lob, LName: lName, FName: fName, City: city, State: state }, function(data) {
        //...process code works 
    }, 'json');
});
```

**EDIT**

I am using the following method to add textbox and dropdown lists...

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })) {%>
<td><%= Html.TextBox("LName")%></td>
<select name="Status" id="Select2"> 
    <option value="ALL">All Policies</option>             
    <option value="Active">Active</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>                                     
</select>
<% } %>
```

Comment: What does have to do with Java?

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar..... Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the text boxes inside `<form>` tags, then use jQuery's `serialize` method.

```
<form id="myForm" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="Input A" />
    <input type="text" name="b" value="Input B" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    $.post("Home/LoadTable", $('#myForm').serialize(), function(data){
        // code...
    },'json');
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  It did.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the way to do it.  You can write a form serializer that would produce the json for you, but you are still going to pass the produced json into it.

Comment: Thanks... is this the same way for Html.Textbox, and Drop downs? See Edit

Answer (score 0):

The following code will loop over all text boxes (no textareas, though) and create an object with the IDs as the key.

```
$('#nameSubmit').click(function () {
    var obj = {};
    $("input:text", this.form).each(function () {
        obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    $.post("Home/LoadTable", obj, function (data) { /* */ }, 'json');
});
```

**EDIT:** Another person suggested using `$().serialize()`, in this use case I strongly support that as the best answer.

Comment: Thanks... is this the same way for Html.Textbox, and Drop downs? See Edit